# How do I get the names of the request parameters for a Spring REST URL?

Tags: spring, spring-rest

I have a Spring REST API and I don't know what the parameter names will be ahead of time.  It's like this ...

`/myapp/api/employees?firstname=Bob&lastname=Jones`

Which basically becomes ... `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE firstname = 'bob' and lastname = 'jones';`

`/myapp/api/customers?customerNumber=12345`

Basically becomes ... `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerNumber = '12345';`

If I knew the params before hand (like 'firstname') then I could do this ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{entityType}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getEntity(@PathVariable String entityType, @RequestParam(required = false) String firstname) throws Exception {
```

... but I don't know the names of the parameters before hand.  They can be anything.

How do I get the list of parameter names that were passed in?

Comment: Have a look at [name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#name--) element of the `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Thanks for the tip ... I googled for more info on RequestParam and found this article ... https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param ... which has a section on "6. Mapping All Parameters" and "multiple parameters without defining their names" ... I think that's what I need.  I'll post an answer when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  Found the solution in [this article here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param) ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{entityType}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getEntity(@PathVariable String entityType, @RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) throws Exception {
```

`allParams` is now a key-value map of all params and values passed it.